# Python np.array with x values into x bins, where each value is represented by 1 bin

Tags: python, arrays, histogram

I have an array with x values ( in this case x=30) and I want to visualize the data with a histogram, using seaborn. Each entry from 0 to 30 should be represented by bin 0 - 30 and the y-axis should be the value of each entry.

I tried
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np

```
array3 = np.random.uniform(0,10, (30))
sns.distplot(array3, bins=30, norm_hist=True)
```

but here the bins don't equal one entry

Comment: Can you show expected output? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: It looks like you need one bar at each x value where the bar height correspond to the value of that entry. In that case, just use `plt.bar(range(len(array)), array)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like the following plot. If not, let me know and I will delete my answer.

```
array3 = np.random.uniform(0,10, (30))
plt.bar(range(len(array3)), array3)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Great. Glad to help!